# Change background color only once the section is scrolled upon

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

The following code scrolls and changes the background upon scroll position but is there any way to get the new background colour to display only once the next section is reached upon scrolling?

It currently changes before even reaching the next div, even after I tried adjusting the `(scroll_pos >= 900)`

Would there be any way to use specific pixel widths for this?

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $('.main-wrap').on('scroll', e => {
    var scroll_pos = $(e.target).scrollTop();
    
    if (scroll_pos > 1500) {
                $("body").css('background-color', 'red');
            } 
    else if  (scroll_pos >= 900) (
                $("body").css('background-color', 'blue'));
                
    else {
                $("body").css('background-color', 'black');}
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.section1, .section2, .section3 {
  background-color: transparent;
  width:100vw; height:10vh
}

/* horizontal styles */
.main-wrap{
width:100vh;
  height:100vw;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(-100vh);
  transform-origin: top left; 
  position:absolute;
  scrollbar-width:none;
  -ms-overflow-style:none;
  
}

.inner-wrap{
  transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-100vh);
  transform-origin: top left; 
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row; 
  width: 300vw;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar{
display:none;
}
```

```html
  
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div class="main-wrap">
  <div class="inner-wrap">
  
  <section class="section1">
    SECTION1
  </section>
  <section class="section2">
    SECTION2
  </section>
    <section class="section3">
    SECTION3
  </section>
</div>  
</div>
```

Comment: All your sections are 100vw wide, so ... go research how to get the viewport width using JavaScript?

Comment: You might fine IntersectionObserver more suitable for this. It will tell you when a section comes into view.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of how your `if/else` statements are written.

```
jQuery($ => {
  $('.main-wrap').on('scroll', e => {
    var scroll_pos = $(e.target).scrollTop();
    
    if (scroll_pos > 1500) {
                $("body").css('background-color', 'red');
            } 
    else if  (scroll_pos >= 900) (
                $("body").css('background-color', 'blue'));
                
    else {
                $("body").css('background-color', 'black');}
  });
});
```

`scroll_pos` starts at zero as soon as you scroll. Let's assume `scroll_pos` is 5. The first `if` returns false. The `elseif` returns false. So only the `else` remains resulting in a black background right away.

If you continue to scroll, eventually you see blue as `scroll_top` exceeds 900.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onscroll=function(){
 if((window.pageYOffset <= 100  || document.documentElement.scrollTop <= 
   100)) {
    
   document.getElementById("body").classList.remove('primary_body');
 }
 else {
    document.getElementById("body").classList.add('primary_body');
 }
}
```

give id body to body

```
<body id="body" style="height:100px" // check body has a height , if it has remove this></body>
```

then give the class a color

```
.primary_body {background-color:red}
```

I was given a scroll value of 100, you can change it as you want, when the scroll is less than 100, it will show the background color

Answer (score 0):

you might wanna get reference to the sections
`var s1 = $('.section1');`

and since your scroller is horizontal,
you'd wanna use

`$('.section1').position().left`

and then test the last section first and first one last.

so your code would be something like

```js
jQuery($ => {    
    var s1 = $(".section1");
    var s2 = $(".section2");
    var s3 = $(".section3");
    
  $('.main-wrap').on('scroll', e => {
      
    if(s3.position().left <= 100 ){
         $("body").css('background-color', 'black')
         .css("color","white");
    }else if(s2.position().left <= 100){
        $("body").css('background-color', 'grey');
    }else if(s1.position().left == 0){
        $("body").css('background-color', 'orange');
    }
  });
});
```

then you can change the value '100' to something else to suit your needs. or just play around with different values and see what happens.